# Gauss-Newton Method not converging for my function

Tags: optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, jacobian, newton-raphson

I need to solve the optimization problem $$ \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{3}}f(x) $$ where  the function $f$ is defined as follows:
$$ f(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(2x_{1}-x_{2}x_{3}-1 \right)^{2}+\left(1-x_{1}+x_{2}-e^{x_{1}-x_{3}}\right)^{2}+\left( -x_{1}-2x_{2}+3x_{3}\right)^{2} \right]$$
using Matlab code for Gauss-Newton's Method.

I already know that the optimal point is $\hat{x}=(1,1,1)$, and my instructions by my professor were to alter my code for Newton's Method by using the Jacobian approximation of the Hessian (i.e, using $\displaystyle H(j,k)\approx 2 \sum_{i=1}^{3}\left[ J(i,j)*J(i,k)\right]$).

After doing this, and running my code for the starting points $(0,0,0)$, $(1.5,0.5,0.5)$, $(2,2,1)$, and $(-1.5,0.5,-0.5)$, I find that the only points it even appears to converge for after 100 iterations are $(0,0,0)$ (appears to converge after 11 iterations, but the algorithm doesn't stop running after that like it did for Newton's Method where it also converged early) and for $(-1.5,0.5,-0.5)$ (appears to converge after 19 iterations, but again, the algorithm doesn't stop running).

These points are not necessarily closer to the optimal point of $(1,1,1)$ than the other starting points. So then, I went to look at the condition index of $J^{T}*J$, because I've read that a high condition index of this matrix could prevent Gauss-Newton from converging.

I calculated the Jacobian Matrix $J$ and its transpose $J^{T}$ at the optimal point of $\hat{x}=(1,1,1)$ and obtained $J = \begin{pmatrix} 9 & -2 & -7 \\ -2 & 6 & -4 \\ -7 & -4 & 11 \end{pmatrix}$, $J^{T} = \begin{pmatrix}9 & -2 & -7 \\ -2 & 6 & -4 \\ -7 & -4 & 11  \end{pmatrix}$ (So, $J$ is a symmetric matrix).

Therefore, $J^{T}*J = \begin{pmatrix} 134 & -2 & -132 \\ -2 & 56 & -54 \\ -132 & -54 & 186 \end{pmatrix}$.

Using Matlab, I calculated the three eigenvalues of this matrix to be $\lambda_{1} = -0.0000$ (I'm assuming this means it is something negative really, really close to zero?), $\lambda_{2} = 74.6686$, $\lambda_{3} = 301.3314$.

First, I calculated the condition index manually by taking the ratio of $\displaystyle \text{max eigenvalue}/\text{min eigenvalue} = \frac{301.3314}{-0.0000} \approx \frac{301.3314}{0}$, which is infinite.

Then, according to the matlab function cond(), the condition index of $J^{T}*J$ was given to be $6.4120e+16$, which is large, but not infinite.

Is this why Gauss-Newton is not converging for this problem?  Is there another reason? Or is it suppose to converge, and am I just doing something wrong?

I thank you ahead of time for your time and patience, and very much look forward to learning how to figure out this problem.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page entry for Gauss-Newton, at least, the update rule for the algorithm requires computing $(J^\top J)^{-1}$. But if $J^\top J$ is singular, then this inverse doesn't exist in the first place. (The the zero (right- and left-) eigenvectors of $J$ are also simple enough to actually write out in the present case.)

Comment: @Semiclassical so is that why it’s not converging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As

$$
f(x) = f(x_0)+\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x}(x-x_0) + \frac 12(x-x_0)^{\dagger}\frac{\partial^2f(x_0)}{\partial^2x}(x-x_0) + O(|x-x_0|^3)
$$

deriving again we have

$$
\nabla f(x)\approx\nabla f(x_0) + \frac{\partial^2f(x_0)}{\partial^2x}(x-x_0)\approx 0
$$

because $f(x) = g_1(x)^2+g_2(x)^2+g_3(x)^2$ so we get

$$
x_k = x_{k-1}-H_{k-1}^{-1}\nabla f(x_{k-1})
$$

with

$$
\nabla f(x) = \frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x} = J\\
H = \frac{\partial^2f(x)}{\partial^2x}\approx J^{\dagger}\cdot J
$$

NOTE

Calling $G(x) = \{g_1(x),g_2(x),\cdots,g_m(x)\}^{\dagger}$ and $f(x) = \frac 12G^{\dagger}(x)\cdot G(x)$ we have

$$
\nabla f(x) = J(x)^{\dagger}\cdot G(x)
$$

and

$$
\nabla^2 f(x) = H(x) = \nabla J(x)^{\dagger}\cdot G(x) + J(x)^{\dagger}\cdot \nabla G(x) = J(x)^{\dagger}\cdot J(x) +\sum_kg_k(x)\nabla^2 g_k(x)
$$

So we can evaluate the approximation

$$
H = \frac{\partial^2f(x)}{\partial^2x}\approx J(x)^{\dagger}\cdot J(x)
$$

Attached a MATHEMATICA script implementing the Gauss-Newton iterative procedure

```
X = {x, y, z};
f[x_, y_, z_] := {{2 x - y z - 1}, {1 - x + y - Exp[x - z]}, {-x - 2 y + 3 z}}
g[x_, y_, z_] := D[f[x, y, z], {X}]
x0 = RandomReal[{-2, 2}];
y0 = RandomReal[{-2, 2}];
z0 = RandomReal[{-2, 2}];
X0 = {x0, y0, z0};
f0 = Flatten[f[x0, y0, z0], 1];
n = 20;
error = 0.0001;
path = {{0, x0, y0, z0, f0.f0}};

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
    Jf = Flatten[Transpose[g[x, y, z] /. Thread[X -> X0]], 1];
    JR = Transpose[Transpose[f[x, y, z]].Jf] /. Thread[X -> X0];
    Hf = Transpose[Jf].Jf;
    p = LinearSolve[Hf, -JR];
    If[Max[Abs[p]] < error, Break[]];
    X0 = Flatten[X0 + p];
    f0 = Flatten[f[x, y, x], 1] /. Thread[X -> X0];
    AppendTo[path, {k, x, y, z, f0.f0} /. Thread[X -> X0]]
]
```

with a typical outcome

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
k & x & y & z & f^{\dagger}\cdot f\\
 0 & -0.18083 & -0.360527 & -1.54181 & 27.0262 \\
 1 & 0.419264 & -0.249572 & -0.0266268 & 2.23994 \\
 2 & 0.441999 & 0.376084 & 0.398056 & 0.101378 \\
 3 & 0.693323 & 0.692737 & 0.692933 & 0.00877097 \\
 4 & 0.846417 & 0.846417 & 0.846417 & 0.000556373 \\
 5 & 0.923209 & 0.923209 & 0.923209 & 0.0000347735 \\
 6 & 0.961604 & 0.961604 & 0.961604 & \text{2.1733}\cdot 10^{-6}
   \\
 7 & 0.980802 & 0.980802 & 0.980802 & \text{1.3583}\cdot 10^{-7} \\
 8 & 0.990401 & 0.990401 & 0.990401 & \text{8.4896}\cdot 10^{-9} \\
 9 & 0.995201 & 0.995201 & 0.995201 & \text{5.3060}\cdot 10^{-10}
   \\
 10 & 0.9976 & 0.9976 & 0.9976 & \text{3.3162}\cdot 10^{-11} \\
 11 & 0.9988 & 0.9988 & 0.9988 & \text{2.0726}\cdot 10^{-12} \\
 12 & 0.9994 & 0.9994 & 0.9994 & \text{1.2954}\cdot 10^{-13} \\
 13 & 0.9997 & 0.9997 & 0.9997 & \text{8.0963}\cdot 10^{-15} \\
 14 & 0.99985 & 0.99985 & 0.99985 & \text{5.0603}\cdot 10^{-16} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Attached a script in octave

```
function [X0,k] = GaussNewton(x0,y0,z0,n,error)
  format long   
  %n     = 20;
  %error = 0.0001;
  %x0    = 0;
  %y0    = 0;
  %z0    = 0;

  X0 = [x0;y0;z0];

  for k = 1:n
    x0 = X0(1);
    y0 = X0(2);
    z0 = X0(3);
    Jf = g(x0,y0,z0);
    JR = (f(x0,y0,z0)'*Jf)';
    Hf = Jf'*Jf;
    p  =-inv(Hf)*JR;
    if max(abs(p)) < error
      break;
    end
    X0 = X0 + p;
  end

end

function fx = f(x,y,z)
  fx = [2.*x-y*z-1.;1.-x+y-exp(x-z);-x-2.*y+3.*z];
end

function dfx = g(x,y,z)
  dfx = [2.,-z,-y;-exp(x-z)-1.,1.,exp(x-z);-1.,-2.,3.];
end
```

Comment: thank you very much, but could you please explain to me what is going on here? Like what conclusion did you come to? Is it actually not converging? Is it converging to $(1,1,1)$? I noticed your error was much finer than what I used. Is that what I need?

Comment: I used the true Hessian instead. With the help of a symbolic processor it is easy to obtain the very formulation for $H^{-1}$ Are you familiar with python? I would post a python algorithm  realization for Newton's method.

Comment: I’m not but I’m also required to use Matlab and Gauss-Newton for this. I’m well aware that Newton’s method, which is essentially what you used here since you used the Hessian rather than the approximation of the Hessian, converges. So, you really did not answer my question at all then. I’m sorry I upvoted before learning that.

Comment: if Gauss-Newton does not converge regardless of the tolerance used, I would appreciate it instead if you could have said so and explained why.

Comment: Added the basic.Gauss-Newton algorithm showing the good convergence.

Comment: Comparing with the Wikipedia article on Newton-Gauss, they've got the update rule as $\beta\to \beta-(J^\top J)^{-1}J^\top r(\beta)$---that is, $(J^\top J)^{-1}J^\top$ rather than $(J^\top J)^{-1}J$ as you have it. (I would tend to believe Wikipedia in this case, since for invertible $J$ we have $(J^\top J)^{-1}J^\top=(J^\top J)^{-1}J^\top J J^{-1} = J^{-1}$ which extends Newton's method nicely.)

Comment: @Cesareo what I noticed was that after so many iterations when it would seem to converge to something close to $(1,1,1)$ that it would then start to zigzag like crazy, never really quite settling down on there. Also, could you please tell me what your initial point was here? That isn’t readily apparent.

Comment: Looking at the table you report (with initial value $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(0.419265, -0.249574, -0.0266273)$) I get the same iterates as you do in my Mathematica implementation, which uses $(J^\top J)^{-1}J^\top =J^{-1}$. So we're in agreement as far as that goes.

Comment: One other observation: To a good approximation, your iterates (and mine) behave like $(x_1,x_2,x_3)_n\approx (1,1,1)+a\cdot 4^{-n}(1,1,1)$. That is, they approach along the $(1,1,1)$ direction with the distance from the optimal point decreasing by a factor of 4 each step. This can presumably be attributed to the fact that $f(1+t,1+t,1+t)=t^4$.

Comment: Typo in my previous remark: the distance decreases by a factor of 2 each step.

Comment: @Cesareo I'm gonna ask you a really stupid question, and I hope that you can humor me here. Is $J^{T}(x)J(x)$ the same thing as $2 \sum_{i=1}^{3}\left[ J(i,j)*J(i,k)\right]$? I'm trying to reconcile the notation in my approximation of the Hessian with the notation in yours.

Comment: @ALannister Given $J = \{a_{i,j}\}$ then $J^{\dagger}\cdot J = \{b_{k,l}\}$ with $b_{k,l} = \sum_{n=1}^3 a_{n,k}a_{n,l}$.

Comment: @Cesareo then without the $2$. Okay. But even with doing that and changing my code accodingly, my code is not giving me the same outputs as yours. What was your initial point here? Let me make sure that at least is the same.

Comment: @ALannister Actually the code generates random numbers as initial points. You can establish a point by inserting after the command $\text{X0 = {x0, y0, z0};}$ this one $X0 = \{2., -1., 3.\};$. The results can be shown with $\text{MatrixForm[path]}$ at the script end

Comment: @Cesareo well it doesn't matter. I still need to use my own code and my input function as it is written is not giving me the same outputs as you. I tried fixing it to see if that would work, and I keep getting errors having to do with type compatibility. So, I am posting a separate question with help on it.

Comment: @Cesareo I'm sure your code is magnificent, but it's not Matlab, and it does not use the Newton's Method code I need to use. All I need to do for this problem is come up with code for a function my ready-made Newton's Method code will call that calculates both the gradient and the approximated Hessian using the Jacobian.

Comment: @Cesareo and what I had before is not giving me convergence anywhere close to what yours was doing. But maybe that's because I picked a different starting point. If you choose $(0,0,0)$ as your starting point, what happens?

Comment: @ALannister Taking from $(0,0,0)$ it converges to the established precision within 13 iterations.

Comment: @Cesareo I rewrote my own code from the ground up and am still not getting your convergence. Somehow, I don't think your code is correct.

Comment: @ALannister My code is published as an answer. You can execute it with MATHEMATICA. It works great.

Comment: @ALannister Attached an octave script covering the algorithm essentials.

Comment: @Cesareo is my problem that I’ve been calculating the Jacobian of the function itself rather than the Jacobian of the residuals? Like here on p. 26? http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/b1/lect2.pdf

Comment: @ALannister Note that in my implementation $f$ is a vector of residues, and $g$ is the residues ($f$) jacobian.

Comment: @Cesareo so you’re saying yes then? Oh man. It had been months since the last time I had seen this stuff before picking it back up again and I had forgotten that that’s how you do it. I feel so incredibly stupid :(